# after browser window close run logout function using javascript or Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Does anyone know anyway that I can use javascript or Vuejs to check when the browser window is close and call logout function? I try this code but when I reload page this function also runs.

I write this code in the default layout.

```
created() {
 window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
       console.log(performance.navigation.type,"performance.navigation.type");
         this.userLogout(); // User Logout Function
        // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
        event.preventDefault();
        // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
        event.returnValue = "";
        (event || window.event).returnValue = null;
        return null;
    }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.onunload` to execute something when the current window is closed.

Refer to the below code.

```
window.onunload = function () {
    // Execute your logout code
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you have to return a string inorder get a confirmation popup. Please find the [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload).

The code should be

```
created() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
       console.log(performance.navigation.type,"performance.navigation.type");
         
       this.userLogout();

       event.preventDefault();

       event.returnValue = '';
    }, false);
}
```

As per the docs,

> When this event returns (or sets the returnValue property to) a value **other than null or undefined**, the user will be prompted to confirm the page unload.

Comment: but this function call after the refresh window also. so I want this function when window close. @Stark Buttowski

Comment: @SandeshMankar Please find the updated snippet. It will call on window reload and close. And also go through docs as browsers handle this differently.